# How to grow an EBS mdadm raid 10 array?

Tags: mdadm, raid-10

Is it possible to grow a RAID 10 array?    Can I take it offline and grow it?  Or do I have to make an entirely new array, and copy all the data onto it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it’s possible, but you have to mess with the superblock. I have seen solutions that simulate RAID10 by creating multiple RAID1 arrays and use LVM to effectively RAID0 the RAID1 arrays, thus creating a hybrid RAID10. I have not tried it myself, but it seems like a good solution. It also allows you to know exactly which disks can be safely failed out, something that is difficult to discern with md.